# Error:In <declare-styleable> ForegroundView, unable to find attribute foreground

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, payment-gateway

I am the getting following errors while i execute paystack3.0.9 android code in android studio 3.

> Error:In  ForegroundView, unable to find attribute foreground
>
> Error:In  ForegroundView, unable to find attribute foregroundInsidePadding
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':paystack:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Application Gradle details:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    }
}
```

Module gradle details:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"
    aaptOptions {
        useNewCruncher false
    }

......


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    android {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }

    compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.3.1'
    compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:1.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.kbeanie:image-chooser-library:1.4.4@aar'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    compile 'co.paystack.android:paystack:3.0.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.19.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

}

After adding "**compile 'co.paystack.android:paystack:3.0.9'**", i am getting the above mentioned error. Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Have you been able to fix this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this issue has been addressed on the issues page of that repo: https://github.com/PaystackHQ/paystack-android/issues/33

Answer (score 0):

Create an `attrs.xml` file in the `values` directory

```
<declare-styleable name="ForegroundView">
   <attr name="foreground" format="color" />
   <attr name="foregroundGravity" format="integer" />
   <attr name="foregroundInsidePadding" format="boolean" />
</declare-styleable>
```